# python fabric parallel pool restrictions

Tags: python, fabric

Have: CentOS 6.5 and Fabric 1.10.0.
I need to run some lightweight commands on ~ 1000-2000 servers by fabric. My env in fabfile.py is:

```
env.parallel = True
env.pool_size = 500
```

So, when I start the fab util and watching processes:

```
# ps ax | grep fab|wc -l
106
# ps ax | grep fab|wc -l
121
# ps ax | grep fab|wc -l
106
# ps ax | grep fab|wc -l
108
```

Why I have not real pool size of 500 processes, only ~ 100? May it be OS restrictions?

Comment: Did you figure this out ? My pool size seems limited to 10 on CentOS ...