# Python - Fabric maximum 10 parallel SSH connections

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I am using `Fabric` with the parallel decorator like so:

```
parallel(pool_size=100)
def mytask():
    # do work
```

I was hoping the program to open 100 distinct SSH connections and run the `Fabric` task on all those servers in parallel.

However, monitoring the number or open SSH connections always gives me an average of 10. I am running on a powerful enough **CentOS** instance.

I am getting the number of concurrent outgoing SSH connections with:

```
sudo netstat -atp | grep "/python"  | grep 10. | grep ssh | wc -l
```

I tried to increase ***MaxSessions*** and ***MaxStartups*** in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but I might not have understood those settings (I am feeling these are setting limits on ***incoming*** SSH connections instead of outgoing).

**Is there a system limit that I need to increase to be able have more than 10 open SSH connections ?**

*Related (no answers):*
[python fabric parallel pool restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308621/python-fabric-parallel-pool-restrictions)

Comment: // , For those of you who'd like an alternative to these performance limitations, you could try ParallelSSH: https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh#fabric

Answer (score 2):

The `get_pool_size` method in the fabric.tasks.Task class is a bit convoluted, trying to guess a not too large pool_size. It returns an integer, after picking values from the global config, task config, default passed, number of hosts.

By my reading of it, it *should* return the minimum of the number_of_hosts and the value you configure in your `parallel` decorator.

Maybe you could just "brute-force" patch that method prior to running the task - Maybe Python's "unittest.mock.patch" decorator can do a prettier job out of this - but it is somewhat complex, and I have no idea how  it would interact with the parallel decorator itself.

So, just monkey patch `get_pool_size` to return 100 at the beginning of your file, and it should work:

```
import fabric.tasks

fabric.tasks.Task.get_pool_size = lambda self: 100

...
```

Comment: This might work, but performance even with one session in fabric is abysmal, never mind with 100. Use a tool that is suited to the task, which fabric is not.